# Jenkins Slave node failed to connect

Tags: jenkins

When launching the node (slave) I get the "Failed to connect error"

The node is configured to run the slave as a windows service. 
There are total 3 nodes connected. All of them configured similarly. Just few weeks back the two of the nodes stopped launching. Happened after a windows patching from the IT department.

Is there anyway to figure out if there is any firewall or port issue?

**Error Log:**

```
[2017-12-20 04:34:07] [windows-slaves] Connecting to MUNTSTPDSQL1
ERROR: Failed to connect: MUNTSTPDSQL1/172.XX.XX.XXX

jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: MUNTSTPDSQL1/172.XX.XX.XXX
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException: Connection in error
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.readn(Transport.java:29)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.peekKey(SmbTransport.java:388)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:288)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doConnect(SmbTransport.java:319)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:258)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.connect(Transport.java:154)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.connect(SmbTransport.java:307)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:156)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:954)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1335)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1417)
at hudson.os.windows.ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.launch(ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.java:219)
at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:262)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.connect(SmbTransport.java:309)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:156)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:954)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1335)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1417)
at hudson.os.windows.ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.launch(ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.java:219)
at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:262)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```